# Prompt for command to reset variable to 1 or any other number

Tags: interactive

I have a command that semi-automates the insertion of numbered chapter headings in an org-mode file.

```
(defun reset-counter ()
  (interactive)
  (setq n 1))

(defun insert-numbered-chapter-headings ()
  "Insert **** 第x章 at cursor point."
  (interactive)
  (insert (format "**** 第%s章"
          n))
  (setq n (+ n 1)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-return>") 'insert-numbered-chapter-headings)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x r") 'reset-counter)
```

Currently, `reset-counter` just sets variable `n` back to 1.

How do I modify the function so that I can be prompted to enter any number other than `1`, with `1` as the default when left blank?

```
(message "String is %s" (read-char "Enter number:")
```

Comment: Can this be done with a if-else statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `read-number` has an optional argument for the default value.  Here is an example:

```lisp
(defvar my-counter nil
  "Doc-string.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-counter)

(defun reset-counter ()
"Doc-string."
  (interactive)
  (let ((temporary-number (read-number "NUMBER:  " 1)))
    (setq my-counter temporary-number)))
```

Comment: The function doesn't pair well with `insert-numbered-chapter-headings`.  Value of `n` remains unchanged after calling `reset-counter`.

Comment: In the example, I am not setting `n` -- I am setting `my-counter` instead.  You did not define `n` in your example as a global or buffer-local variable and I wished to avoid any confusion you may have had in that regard.  In this example, I let-bound `n` locally for only the duration of the function.  As such, it will not modify `n` if you have that as a buffer-local or global variable.  I would suggest using unique names for buffer-local or global variables, and I would also suggest that you define them specifically instead of just creating them with `setq` -- that way you can visit the code.

Comment: I changed the `n` to `temporary-number` to avoid further confusion; and, I added a doc-string to the `defvar` statement so that we can look it up with `M-x describe-variable` and/or `M-x find-variable`.