# How to check whether an optional param was input?

Tags: debugging, variables, arguments

I have a command with an optional argument whose value is a number. 
I need:

If no input argument then use default value (1000) else use input arg.

```
(random t) 
(defun insert-random-number-at-point(&optional to)
  "Insert at point a random number (default from 0 to 1000)."
  (interactive "nInsert at point a random number (default from 0 to 1000): ")
  (if (= (to) nil)
      (insert (number-to-string (random 1000))) ;; then use default value
    (insert (number-to-string to)))) ;; else
```

Start :

```
Insert at point a random number (default from 0 to 1000): 15
```

Error:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: to
```

Comment: `(to)` tries to invoke `to` as a function. Lose the parentheses, to use its value as a variable. `(if (= to nil)...)` is simpler as `(if to ...)`.

Comment: And `=` is the wrong predicate - its args need to be numbers or markers.

Comment: Instead of testing whether <something> is `nil`, just test <something>, that is, test whether it's non-`nil`. And instead of using conditionals, just `(setq to (or to (random 1000)))` or `(unless to (setq to (random 1000)))`.

Answer (score 4):

In Lisp, the term/word that follows an open parenthesis (if the open parenthesis is not quoted) is interpreted to be a *function*, not a *variable*.  In the context of this question, `to` is a *variable*.  Because the word `to` follows an open parenthesis that is not quoted, Emacs thinks it was meant to be interpreted as a *function* instead of a *variable*.  Try instead using `(if to (insert ....` -- which tests whether the *variable* `to` has been assigned a value.

When using the function `=`, Emacs expects that two integers will be compared.  Inasmuch as `nil` is not a number, Emacs will throw an error:  `(wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)`.  However, using `=` here appears to not be needed as explained in the preceding paragraph.

Another way to test whether a variable has been assigned a value is to use the function `null`:

```
null is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(null OBJECT)

Return t if OBJECT is nil, and return nil otherwise.
```

So we could use `(if (not (null to)) ...`

Comment: (if to (insert (number-to-string (random 1000))) -> it's always ask me about number. But I want , if not input number, then use default value.

Comment: How about using `(if (not to) ...` instead?

Comment: I't always ask me about input number. When I pres RET it show message "Please, enter a number". But I want when press RET to use default value

Comment: According to the documentation, the interactive code `n`:  "*A number, read with the minibuffer. If the input is not a number, the user has to try again. ‘n’ never uses the prefix argument. Prompt.*"  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html  Perhaps you want to use `read-number` in the body instead of as an interactive code such as `n` and set the default value to something like -1 or zero and test for that default value ...  The function `read-number` has an optional argument for a default value.  See ... https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/52323/2287